# How to reduce the quality of the text inside UITextView with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview, blurry, catextlayer

I'm trying to reduce the quality of a message before its being sent, for example if the connect is poor I want to blur out the text in the `UITextView` and if connection improves or internet comes back, then remove the blur and show the normal text in the `UITextView`. I have tried using `CATextLayer` doesn't work. Is there a way I can achieve this?

```
cell.messageTextView.text = theText

let textLayer = CATextLayer()
textLayer.string = cell.messageTextView.text
textLayer.contentsScale = 0.2
cell.messageTextView.layer.addSublayer(textLayer)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you please share sample screenshots

Comment: @Hitesh i have added the screenshot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can drop the quality of the layer by making it rasterized and reducing the scale of it:

```
let badQualityRatio: CGFloat = 4
textView.layer.shouldRasterize = true
textView.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale/badQualityRatio
```

#### Result:

[image: Result]

<sub>you can set the `rasterizationScale` any number between 0 and `UIScreen.main.scale`</sub>

Comment: This doesn't work on the `UITextView` i'm using. You are using a `UILabel`

Comment: This is different from your code. the point is to change the main layer `scale` after making it `rasterized` *not* adding another `sublayer`. Let me know if you have problem with the code.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini, can we achieve this type of [blur effect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64428968/blur-uitextviews-text) using the above code or any other technique then it will be helpful

Comment: You should make an image from the text, then blur it with the existing methods. But it has its costs.

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini thank you for the quick response, `But it has its costs.` which type of costs --> performance, etc,

Comment: It is premature optimization to say but for a total view, costs of learning, implementing, real-time applying performance hits, etc. It totally depends on you and your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemUltraThinMaterial)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = cell.view.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
cell.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
```

Adding a UIVisualEffectView with blur effect on top of your table view cell.