# Blur UITextView's text

Tags: swift, uitextview, uivisualeffectview

I'm using [VisualEffectView](https://github.com/efremidze/VisualEffectView) GitHub library to blur the text of `UItextView` but I want to blur text, not the whole view. As you see in the image when applying an effect, we are able to see the edges of the view. Can anyone help me out with how to achieve this by using the `VisualEffectView` library or any other techniques? Any help would be appreciated.

**Code:**

```
var visualEffectViewDescription = VisualEffectView()


visualEffectViewDescription.frame = self.descriptionOfWorkout.bounds
visualEffectViewDescription.blurRadius = 3
self.descriptionOfWorkout.addSubview(visualEffectViewDescription)
```

[image]

Comment: Is a blur such as the one shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59372278/how-to-reduce-the-quality-of-the-text-inside-uitextview-with-swift) acceptable?

Comment: @Sweeper sorry, not required that type of blur

Comment: Asking for a library is off topic on stack overflow.